# Cassandra: Writing binary blob to table with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra

I am trying to have my node.js app read a file and then add it to a table but I can not figure it out.

Here is the table info

```
CREATE TABLE tracking.tracking_data (
first_name text,
last_name text,
timestamp timestamp,
heat double,
location text,
m blob,
speed double,
telepathy_powers int,
PRIMARY KEY ((first_name, last_name), timestamp)
```

Here is the node.js code:

```
var populateData = function(first_name, last_name, timestamp, heat, location, speed, telepathy_powers, file) {
fs.readFile(file, 'binary', function(err, data) {
if (err) {
return console.log(err);
} else {
var client = new cassandra.Client({
contactPoints: ['node1', 'node2', 'node3'],
keyspace: 'tracking'
});
var query = 'INSERT INTO tracking_data (first_name,last_name,timestamp,heat,location,m,speed,telepathy_powers) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);';
const parms = [first_name, last_name, timestamp, heat, location, data, speed, telepathy_powers];
client.execute(query, parms, {
prepare: true
}, function(err, result) {
if (err) {
console.log('\n' + err);
}
});
}
});
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: Not a valid blob, expected Buffer obtained 'root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/ash\nbin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin\ndaemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin\nadm:x:3:4:adm:/var/adm:/sbin/nologin\nlp:x:4:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/sbin/nologin\nsync:x:5:0:sync:/sbin:/bin/sync\nshutdown:x:6:0:shutdown:/sbin:/sbin/shutdown\nhalt:x:7:0:halt:/sbin:/sbin/halt\nmail:x:8:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is because you specified the encoding for file, even although it's binary.  Cassandra driver needs `Buffer` type that is returned when `fs.readFile` is called only with file name & handler, without encoding (see [`fs.readFile` docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)).

Comment: How? I do not see anywhere to do it. It will not even let me upvote your answer because this is a new account.

Comment: Hmmm, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers ? If doesn’t work - then leave it as-is...